# Run batch file with arguments

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file from c#. The purpose is to create a simple file when the batch file executes. Seems its not working.

Here is the batch file code

**one.bat**

```
echo %*
copy NUL EmptyFile.txt
pause
```

**C# Code**

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c C:\\Users\ABC\\Desktop\\F1\\one.bat \"a\" b c ");
```

C# code runs fine and also seems like calls the bat file, but the new file in the batch file is not getting created.

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: If you execute the .bat manually on cmd, works as it should work?

Comment: Yes, it did. That’s what confuses me

Comment: As a side note, you may consider using [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) for launching command line executables (or batch files).

Comment: As @gabriel-luci points out, you need to specify the full path, the file should be in the project's bin/debug folder

Comment: If you really wanted to use `copy` then use `echo y | copy NUL newfile.ext > Nul`. Alternatively I would suggest using either `break > newfile.ext` or `type NUL > newfile.ext`.

Comment: Why use a batch file for this at all?  Why not just `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\pathtofile\emptyfile.txt", null);` ?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, in my case its calling a 3rd party batch file, which does much more than file creation. I wanted to get the calling batch script in place and file creation is a part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't specifying where `EmptyFile.txt` should go, so it's trying to put it in the default working directory, which happens to be Windows' system32 directory, which the process probably doesn't have access to.

You can either use a full path in your bat file (`copy NUL C:\Temp\EmptyFile.txt`) or change your code to use a [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_) object and set the [`WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_WorkingDirectory) to whatever you want.

Comment: WorkingDirectory solved the issue for me. Thank you.